# How to solve JVM Crash?

Tags: java, jvm

I got following JVM crash error. May I know how to solve this? Please refer to following hs_err log.

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:
#
#  Internal Error (50532D41524B33574545502445434F5241544F520E4350500024), pid=18211, tid=1137465664
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (1.5.0_22-b03 mixed mode)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00002aab6407df10):  VMThread [id=18260]

Stack: [0x0000000043bc5000,0x0000000043cc6000),  sp=0x0000000043cc4850,  free space=1022k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x667711]
V  [libjvm.so+0x2e4c66]
V  [libjvm.so+0x5a899d]
V  [libjvm.so+0x5a8ade]
V  [libjvm.so+0x5b11f4]
V  [libjvm.so+0x5a76e6]
V  [libjvm.so+0x5b29bb]
V  [libjvm.so+0x57d04d]
V  [libjvm.so+0x67003a]
V  [libjvm.so+0x66fa5a]
V  [libjvm.so+0x66f176]
V  [libjvm.so+0x66f3eb]
V  [libjvm.so+0x66ef7a]
V  [libjvm.so+0x56ff45]

VM_Operation (0x000000004138c420): parallel gc failed allocation, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x000000001ed29460


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000001ed29460 JavaThread "CobolThread 362" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6054]
  0x000000001ac8e4f0 JavaThread "CobolThread 361" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6038]...
```

May I know if the above error could be solved by just changing the JVM argument? Following is the JVM argument currently using.

```
-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=768m -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

Comment: To begin with, can't you use a more recent JVM ? And do you really need to use this GC algorithm ?

Answer (score 8):

You use an old VM and specify a GC algorithm using an option explicitly  non stable :

> Options that are specified with -XX are not stable and are subject to
>   change without notice.

(from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

This line of your trace shows that the failure is related to the parallel gc :

```
VM_Operation (0x000000004138c420): parallel gc failed allocation
```

So if you don't have a really specific reason to use this parameterization, remove it. You should only choose a GC algorithm when you know why. And update your VM, as it's harder to search for the bugs of this old version.

Comment: pretty much every gc param is "-XX", so not sure what your reasoning is here.  never use anything but the vanilla gc settings?

Comment: Never use a GC parameter if you can't justify why you used it.

Comment: okay.  so assuming the OP needs it, how does this answer their question?  (i agree w/ the old jvm bit, though)

Comment: I think that if OP was needing it, he would have explained it as the error clearly shows that the failure is related to the parallel gc.

Comment: k, maybe you could call that out a little more explicitly in your answer.

Comment: As it was in the middle, I thought it was obvious but you're right, it's better to be more explicit. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your comment.
The reason of using Parallel GC is that I need to process a large transaction which only only one commit and this causes outOfMemory error. This error was solved after adding the Parallel GC. Any other option other than Parallel GC to release memory when processing large transaction ?

Comment: Did you try with a recent JVM. I'm no specialist of parallel GC but I think this was new in 5.0 and probably got better after.

Comment: I can't upgrade the JVM to latest version as other application still using 5.0. In addition, this problem is not easy to be replicated. So, even I upgrade to 7, may not easy to determine whether it is solved or not.